# Exception when opening a excel file in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jexcelapi

I have a problem when trying to display a `MsExcel` file in a `JFrame`. The exception is like this: `com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException`.

here is the code:

```
    public jexcelTest1() throws ExcelException{

        JFrame frame= new JFrame("Test application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout( new BorderLayout());
        JWorkbook workbook = new JWorkbook();
        cp.add(workbook);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500 );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

And the exception message is:

> Exception in thread "main" com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException: Cannot find JNIWrapper native library (jniwrap.dll) in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;.

I already added the following libraries: comfyj-2.8.jar, jexcel-1.5.jar, jniwrap-3.8.2.jar, slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar, slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar, winpack-3.8.2.jar

Could you clarify this for me please.
Thank you.

Comment: It says that it cannot find "jniwrap.dll", yet you don't mention having added the jniwrap.dll library. Can you try that first?

Comment: Yes thank you Mr Myers. I tried it so I have palced it in the main jar file and finally this exception disapoeared ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also add the DLL's (that come with TeamDev's API) either to the system path (I think `system32`) or, as prefer, add the DLL's directly to the default package of your applications Jar

Comment: Thank you this work now. But another problem apear it's the license files that I have to use JExcel.

Comment: The license files should like in the META-INF directory of your source.  These need to be packaged up with at least one Jar in your project (so they can found on the classpath). I simply created a small project that contains the DLL's and the licenses and include into all the projects I want to use these in, saves having to remember it each time ;)